# How can the source attachment, Javadoc location and native library location be specified for a Gradle project's local dependency, in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, gradle, gradle-eclipse, buildship

The Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Neon) as well as the default Gradle plugin (Buildship?) are used.

A Gradle Git project was created using the Eclipse IDE. A local JAR is stored within the `workspace/ProjectName/lib/nameOfJAR.jar` directory. It was added to this project as a dependency, using the following *build.gradle* configuration.

```
...

repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()

    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib/'
    }

}

dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

    compile name: 'nameOfJAR'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then `Project Explorer > Project A > Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project` was used to update the Eclipse GUI, to display this new local dependency, via `Project Explorer > Project A > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries > Project and External Dependencies > [Name of JAR]`.

However, when expanding this section, source attachment, Javadoc location and native library location are shown as *non modifiable*. Can these be set from the Gradle configuration files?

How can these be set through Eclipse and Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can place `nameOfJar-sources.jar` file next to the actual library in the same directory. Gradle will use that as a source attachment. I suppose the same would work for javadocs, that is `nameOfJar-javadoc.jar` would be picked up. I don't know how native libs are handled.

This is probably described somewhere in the Gradle docs, but I don't know where to find them.

Comment: I would prefer to set custom paths/filenames, if possible. However, I cannot find the related page of documentation. Anyways, thank you for your response.